# How to return user defines class in JMX?

Tags: jmx

I am new to JMX and now I wished to monitor my project with JMX. Is there any way to return user defined class via MBeans/MXBean? I know that OpentType can help but don't know how to used it. I also went through Composite and Tabular data types but it may not work for me because I need to convert each and every class into respective data types.
Please provide your help.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Interface `SomethingMBean` and a class that implement that interface.

```
public interface HelloMBean { 

    public void sayHello(); 
    public int add(int x, int y); 

    public String getName(); 

    public int getCacheSize(); 
    public void setCacheSize(int size); 
} 

public class Hello ... 
    implements HelloMBean { 
    public void sayHello() { 
        System.out.println("hello, world"); 
    } 

    public int add(int x, int y) { 
        return x + y; 
    } 

    public String getName() { 
        return this.name; 
    }  

    public int getCacheSize() { 
        return this.cacheSize; 
    } 

    public synchronized void setCacheSize(int size) {
        ...

        this.cacheSize = size; 
        System.out.println("Cache size now " + this.cacheSize); 
    } 
    ...

    private final String name = "Reginald"; 
    private int cacheSize = DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE; 
    private static final int 
        DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE = 200; 
}
```

And then, you have to register your MBean...

```
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(); 
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("com.example:type=Hello"); 
Hello mbean = new Hello(); 
mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name);
```

Take a look at [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is using Spring, then it is quite easy to expose any user-defined class to JMX by simply using annotations:

- @ManagedResource - to expose the class to JMX
- @ManagedAttribute - to expose any fields of a ManagedResource class as attributes
- @ManagedOperation - to expose any method of a ManagedResource class
  as an operation

Have a look at the [official Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html) which contains quite a few illustrative examples as well.